# ¿Como evitar que un contenedor para desarrollo (dev-container) en VSCODE se cierre al terminar proceso?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Actualmente estoy desarrollando en un contenedor de [Odoo](https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo), pero cada vez que el proceso principal termina y tengo adjunto VSCODE necesito recargar para que se conecte de nuevo.

Para prevenir esto, dentro de `.devcontainer` modifique el fichero `docker-compose.yml` con la siguiente linea:

```
#....más configuraciones
# Overrides default command so things don't shut down after the process ends.
command: /bin/sh -c "while sleep 1000; do :; done"
```

Este es mi `devcontainer.json`:

```
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the README at:
// https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/v0.245.2/containers/docker-existing-docker-compose
// If you want to run as a non-root user in the container, see .devcontainer/docker-compose.yml.
{
        "name": "Existing Docker Compose (Extend)",

        // Update the 'dockerComposeFile' list if you have more compose files or use different names.
        // The .devcontainer/docker-compose.yml file contains any overrides you need/want to make.
        "dockerComposeFile": [
                "../docker-compose.yml",
                "docker-compose.yml"
        ],

        // The 'service' property is the name of the service for the container that VS Code should
        // use. Update this value and .devcontainer/docker-compose.yml to the real service name.
        "service": "web",

        // The optional 'workspaceFolder' property is the path VS Code should open by default when
        // connected. This is typically a file mount in .devcontainer/docker-compose.yml
        "workspaceFolder": "/home",

        // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
        // "forwardPorts": [],

        // Uncomment the next line if you want start specific services in your Docker Compose config.
        // "runServices": [],

        // Uncomment the next line if you want to keep your containers running after VS Code shuts down.
        // "shutdownAction": "none",

        // Uncomment the next line to run commands after the container is created - for example installing curl.
        // "postCreateCommand": "apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl",

        // Uncomment to connect as a non-root user if you've added one. See https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/containers/non-root.
        "remoteUser": "root"
}
```

Aun con todo estó al obtener un error debo levantar de nuevo el contenedor con `docker-compose up` lo que provoca que se desconecte VSCODE.

Dentro del contenedor utilizo una opción de configuración que reinicia el servicio cada vez que detecta cambio en el código, similar a la función de `nodemon` en nodejs, pero a diferencia de `nodemon`, si se presenta un error grave "no compilable" el servicio se detiene completamente y sale con un código de error.

¿Como puedo lograr evitar este comportamiento? Hay manera de ignorar el código de error para no tener que estar recargando vscode?

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de tu docker-compose, en el servicio que deseas mantener, puedes agregar la siguiente línea:

```
command: /bin/sh -c "while sleep 1000; do :; done"
```

*Esto evitará que el proceso se termine.